# How to solve "AttributeError: 'KNeighborsClassifier' object has no attribute 'n_samples_fit_'"?

Tags: flask, web-applications, classification, attributeerror, knn

i am using KNeighborsClassifier to classify flowers with the famous iris dataset.

I have done the training, and now going to deploy it as web app.

But the problem is, when i test the app locally, it shows this,

```
AttributeError: 'KNeighborsClassifier' object has no attribute 'n_samples_fit_'
```

[image: The error message]

I googled a lot, and still can't find the solution.

The app is here, https://github.com/josephofiowa/GA_iris, it wasn't written by me by the way.

i found a post here, but it is about image recognition https://github.com/pliablepixels/zmeventnotification/issues/188
i am not sure it is related, but i still post it here. It says it is a version problem, but how do I downgrade?

Thank you guys!

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, session, redirect, url_for
from flask.ext.wtf import Form
from wtforms import IntegerField, StringField, SubmitField, SelectField, DecimalField
from wtforms.validators import Required
import pickle
from sklearn import datasets

# Initialize Flask App
app = Flask(__name__)


print("loading my model")
with open('model.pkl', 'rb') as handle:
    machine_learning_model = pickle.load(handle)
print("model loaded")


# Initialize Form Class
class theForm(Form):
    param1 = DecimalField(label='Sepal Length (cm):', places=2, validators=[Required()])
    param2 = DecimalField(label='Sepal Width (cm):', places=2, validators=[Required()])
    param3 = DecimalField(label='Petal Length (cm):', places=2, validators=[Required()])
    param4 = DecimalField(label='Petal Width (cm):', places=2, validators=[Required()])
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    print(session)
    form = theForm(csrf_enabled=False)
    if form.validate_on_submit():  # activates this if when i hit submit!
        # Retrieve values from form
        session['sepal_length'] = form.param1.data
        session['sepal_width'] = form.param2.data
        session['petal_length'] = form.param3.data
        session['petal_width'] = form.param4.data
        # Create array from values
        flower_instance = [[(session['sepal_length']),(session['sepal_width']),(session['petal_length']),(session['petal_width'])]]

        # Return only the Predicted iris species
        flowers = ['setosa', 'versicolor', 'virginica']
        session['prediction'] = flowers[machine_learning_model.predict(flower_instance)[0]]

        # Implement Post/Redirect/Get Pattern
        return redirect(url_for('home'))

    return render_template('home.html', form=form, **session)


# Handle Bad Requests
@app.errorhandler(404)
def page_not_found(e):
    return render_template('404.html'), 404

app.secret_key = 'super_secret_key_shhhhhh'
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please take some time to do the [tour] and to learn how to [ask]. Your posts contains links to images or repositories which may change, can't be copied, etc. Post the relevant code you have thus far here and explain where it is going wrong.

Comment: thank you Ronald, i edited the question, hope it is clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

try with machine_learning_model.knn_.n_samples_fit_=flower_instance.shape[0]

recently tried similar solution in one of

Comment: thank you @Sayantan would you please tell me more about it? like where does this syntax go? or which should i substitute it with?